# How to convert a string to date with AM/PM?

Tags: datetime, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to convert a string to timestamp in Hive

String: `11/25/2014 07:58:37 AM`

This command works but ignores the halfday of day:

```
select unix_timestamp(ClosedDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss') from ...
```

I tried this:

```
unix_timestamp(ClosedDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a')
```

and this:

```
unix_timestamp(ClosedDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt')
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

the problem was in hour format.

```
    unix_timestamp(ClosedDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')
```